# iteratively run function in R with no need to return object

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a list of dataframes that I want to store in a SQL database. Currently I am using a for-loop to connect to the database, take each list element (a data.frame) and then store it as a table in my SQL database. However, the for-loops are relatively slow.

I use `lapply()` quite liberally in my work, but the most appropriate use of it is to return a list object. Rather than a for-loop is there an efficient way to just execute a function that doesn't necessarily return an object?

Here's an example of my code, though I don't see much use in a regex since this is more of a general question rather than asking for help to catch a bug.

```
dfList <- list(
    data.frame(a = (0, 1), b = (0, 1), c = (0, 1)), 
    data.frame(a = (1, 0), b = (1, 0), c = (1, 0))
)

for (i in 1: datasets) {
   # extract the data.frame list element
   df <- dfList[[i]]
   # then put it in my SQL database as its own table
   DBI::dbWriteTable(
       engine,
       paste0("table", as.character(i)), 
       df,
       overwrite = TRUE
   )
}
```

Maybe something like `do.call()`?

Comment: You seem to be making a copy of each data frame before writing it. Why not `Map(function(d, i) DBI::dbWriteTable(engine, paste0("table", as.character(i)), d, overwrite = TRUE), d = dfList, i = seq_along(dfList))`? I'm not sure this will provide much of a speed-up though, since it's likely that the writing operations are taking up most of the time.

Comment: you could use `purrr:walk()`; however, its more decorative than functional --  that is, I would be surprised if it helped with the efficiency problem that you mention.

Comment: @AllanCameron, thank you for your responses! I tried it out with Map and that seems to do the job. I'm sure it is the writing the table part that takes the longest, but honestly, any small efficiency gain would be pretty helpful for me. So much appreciated!

Comment: @langtang thank you for your comment, I'll check out `purrr::walk()`!